# how change learnrate and hidden layers of a MLP network with sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, mlp

I'm doing a cross validation with sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score function to a multilayer perceptron

```
from sklearn import svm
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

clf = svm.SVC(gamma='auto')

scores = cross_val_score(clf, X, np.ravel(y), cv=5, scoring='accuracy')
```

The cross validation is working and returning 0.8579100145137881.
How can I change de number of learnrate or hidden layers with the sklearn? I want improve the accuracy.

Comment: svm.SVC is a support vector machines classifier, not a multilayer perceptron. So your first problem is you are using the wrong sklearn function. First thing to do would be to use the multilayer perceptron (if that's really what you want) under https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html . Their documentation (at same link) clearly explains how to change the learning rate and number of hidden layers.

Comment: And how can I do a cross validation with this multilayer perceptron?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from sklearn import svm
import numpy as np

from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
clf = MLPClassifier(solver='sgd', hidden_layer_sizes=(4,4), learning_rate_init=0.05, activation='logistic', max_iter=30000)

from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
scores = cross_val_score(clf, X, np.ravel(y), cv=5, scoring='accuracy')
```